# How to Call SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure from CSHTML page

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

From the question you may realize I'm not very versed in this. This is actually my first time.

I have an HTML page with a form that asks for a phone number. When the user clicks on the submit button, it goes to a CSHTML page that takes the phone number from the form by doing this:

```
@{
string pn = Request.Form["pn"]
}
```

Then it has to call a stored procedure with that value (`pn`) as a parameter.

Stored procedure name: `sp_AddPNtoDNC`

Server: `SqlSrv`

Username: `insusr`

PW: `whatever`

Please, don't assume I know anything!

Oh, one more thing. I'm doing all this from a recently installed WebMatrix.

Thanks.

Comment: You should avoid using sp_ as a prefix for your procedures http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this the "WebMatrix way", you would use the Database helper.

First you need to add a connection string to your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myConnection" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then at the top of the cshtml file:

```
var db = Database.Open("myConnection");
db.Execute("EXEC sp_AddPNtoDNC @0", Request.Form["pn"]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the way to do it. One one hand I prefer it, not to expose the connection sting. On the other way, I'd like to understand why so say "the WebMatrix way". Isn't WebMatrix just another way of "generating code"? Shouldn't everything work the same way regardless of how the code was generated with WebMatrix, Visual Studio or typed up in Notepad?

Comment: WebMatrix was designed to assist with ASP.NET development using the Web Pages framework. A number of "helpers" come with that framework which are designed to simplify web development. The Database helper and Razor syntax are two examples. You can indeed use ADO.NET as Veeesss illustrated, or Entity Framework or a number of other data access options, but the Database helper is the simplest - fewer lines of code.

Comment: I guess there's A LOT to learn here for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("sp_AddPNtoDNC", conn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pn", pn));

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You can try something like this.

I hope this help you.